# I got error " Invalid Key Hash XXXXXXXXXXX does not match any stored key hashes " in realise mode in android?

Tags: android-facebook

I develop facebook integration with android. App is running in build mode its working fine but while run in realise mode app is not working. How can i resolve this problem? I got error "  Invalid Key Hash XXXXXXXXXXX does not match any stored key hashes .

Comment: Seriously, how can we help you on this without seing any code... Show code, what you've tried and then maybe people will be able to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For people looking for answer:

We need to add both- release and debug keys under your project in Facebook developer site.

[image]

Here are the steps I followed:

1. create keystore by running this command:

> ```
> ...\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin>keytool -exportcert -likeytool -genkey -v -keystore <APP_NAME>.keystore -alias <APP_NAME> -keyalg RSA -validity 999999
> ```

2. You have already added the debug key. Now generate a release key and add it under you project.

> ..\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias  -keystore .keystore file> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

3. Sign your app in the release mode.